# Setting up ssh tunnel in Putty

Tags: windows, ssh, proxy, putty, tunnel

I have instructions for setting up a proxy tunnel to a work computer behind a firewall. The setup is:

```
                        |
[home]--------[outside]-|-[inside]
                        |
```

The instructions are, from home:

1. ssh -N -L 7000:inside:22 outside
2. ssh -D 9999 -p 7000 localhost
3. Setup a proxy for port 9999 on localhost

I should then be able to appear to the world as though I'm on [inside].

If I was on a mac or linux machine I assume I would do the first two steps in order at a terminal. In windows, I can't just open up an ssh terminal.

The putty tunnel configuration screen looks like this:

[image]

I have two questions:

1. What would be the right settings for step 1?
2. Is the 2nd step done in Putty as well, or from the shell connection in step 1?

**Edit:**
This is what the main Putty screen looks like:

[image]

Localhost:7000

[image]

Answer (score 1):

So to answer your second question first, yes, both steps are done from PuTTY.

First you need to setup a tunnel to `outside` using the "Local" radio button with the "Source Port" set to `7000` and the "Destination" set to `inside:22`.

Next, you would start another instance of PuTTY and use `localhost:7000` as the host.  On the tunnels tab, select the "Dynamic" radio button and set the "Source Port" to `9999`.

Then, as before, configure your proxy to point to `localhost:9999`.

Comment: Thanks! Do I need to put anything in the "Destination" box for either step? Also, What do I put for hostname in step 2? See image added to question. Is it just `outside` again?

Comment: @abalter, I've updated the answer to clarify

Comment: Putty won't connect when I have it set as in image above: hostname=localhost, port=7000. Isn't that kind of like asking to log on to my own machine at port 7000? I'm not running an ssh server.

Comment: I just realized I wrote that wrong.  The first step should have "Local" selected, not "Remote."  I've updated the answer.  This will open port `7000` on the **local** machine and forwarding it to `inside:22` on the remote side of the tunnel

Comment: So does that take care of both steps at once?

Comment: No, you still need both.  The first one opens a session to `outside` and the tunnel opens port `7000` on the local machine.  Any connections to `localhost:7000` will then be forwarded to `inside:22`, so you connect the second session to `localhost:7000` and then setup the second, dynamic tunnel which you will use as the proxy.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/33141/discussion-between-abalter-and-heavyd).